# Angular 5 - ssr weird error

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5, angular-universal

I have created angular 5 universal SSR server by this tutorial: https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-fundamentals-universal-server-side-rendering

TypeError: o.default is not a function
at new  (/deluxesenior/frontend/dist-server/main.bundle.js:1:156926)
at _createClass (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10956:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10928:26)
at initNgModule (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10881:28)
at new NgModuleRef_ (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12135:9)
at createNgModuleRef (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12125:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:14469:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:15614:25)
at /deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5531:78
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/deluxesenior/frontend/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:392:26)

I can provide any code but i don’t know what is causing this error so i don’t know which files should I paste here.

Comment: can you add code to the post

Comment: I can but i won’t paste here entire application... which file or code or information should I paste?

Comment: which file throws error you can post that alone

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kbhysf1x - I pasted it here because its to long

Comment: Please add more codes (not just error), I recommend you this read this [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/angular-server-side-rendering-using-angular-cli-bbde0c0eefe9) and follow its steps to consider what's server-side rendering, and how to implement it.

Comment: Can you add your package.json file

Comment: @David - here you go https://pastebin.com/EtbHmzHH

Comment: How to you import modules from redux in your code?